# GMSAutocompleteTableDataSourceDelegate of Google places API works partially for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, google-places-api

I implemented GMSAutocompleteTableDataSourceDelegate for my project. I see the data is loading based on the search result. However, when I click on the result its corresponding delegate method is not getting called.

Following delegate methods are getting called

```
    func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(for tableDataSource: GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        resultsController?.tableView.reloadData()

    }
    func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(for tableDataSource: GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        resultsController?.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

After the selecting the address from the suggestion, ideally it is supposed to call one of the following methods. However, none of the methods are getting called.

```
    func tableDataSource(_ tableDataSource: GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

    }

    func tableDataSource(_ tableDataSource: GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {

    }

    func tableDataSource(_ tableDataSource: GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource, didSelect prediction: GMSAutocompletePrediction) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

It will be great if, somebody can give me some idea how to tackle it or some debugging tips

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The reason was there was a UIGesture delegate for the view. Because of this delegate method, it was canceling all the events.